# WSL Matplotlib artifacts

Tags: python, matplotlib, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am trying to run matplotlib.pyplot on WSL in a Conda environment, but on start some strange things happen to my pyplot window, there are weird lines (that sometimes hide on hover).

WSL versions:

```
WSL version: 2.0.14.0
Kernel version: 5.15.133.1-1
WSLg version: 1.0.59
MSRDC version: 1.2.4677
Direct3D version: 1.611.1-81528511
DXCore version: 10.0.25131.1002-220531-1700.rs-onecore-base2-hyp
Windows version: 10.0.22631.3155
```

Conda versions (matplotlib & python):

```
matplotlib                3.8.0           py311h06a4308_0  
matplotlib-base           3.8.0           py311ha02d727_0  
matplotlib-inline         0.1.6              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
python                    3.11.7               h955ad1f_0
```

[image: Pyplot window]

After a click in the window, the window corrects itself:
[image: Corrected window]

But after a hover into the plot in the window, there is still a line with artifacts:
[image: Window with a line of artifacts]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Noticed that the plot window contains "[WARN: COPY MODE]", so searched for answers for this and I solved it with updating mesa like so: `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:kisak/kisak-mesa`.
Props to [onomatopellan](https://github.com/microsoft/wslg/discussions/312).